# virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts could not find get_env_details

Tags: python, virtualenv, osx-mavericks, homebrew, virtualenvwrapper

When I run `mkvirtualenv TESTING`:

```
New python executable in TESTING/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in TESTING/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts could not run "/Users/admin/.virtualenvs/TESTING/bin/preactivate": [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

A similar error appears when I run `lsvirtualenv`:

```
bpython-dev
===========
virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts could not run
"/Users/admin/.virtualenvs/bpython-dev/bin/get_env_details": [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I've checked into the .virtualenvs/bpython-dev/ (and other virtual envs) to see if get_env_details is there, and it is.

This problem happened after I performed Migration Assistant with Time Machine on Mavericks.

I'm using Python 2 installed with Homebrew.
`which python` yields `usr/local/bin/python` and `which pip` yields `usr/local/bin/pip`.

My `.bash_profile`:

```
# Load /usr/local/ before /usr/bin/
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH


# Load the default .profile
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile"


# Virtualenvwrapper
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Hacker\ School/
export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=$WORKON_HOME
export PIP_RESPECT_VIRTUALENV=true
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh 


# Timing terminal directory tracking
PROMPT_TITLE='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME%%.*}:${PWD/#$HOME/~}\007"'
export PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND} ${PROMPT_TITLE}; "

export DJANGO_COLORS="dark"


# _django_completion()
# {
#     COMPREPLY=( $( COMP_WORDS="${COMP_WORDS[*]}" \
#                    COMP_CWORD=$COMP_CWORD \
#                    DJANGO_AUTO_COMPLETE=1 $1 ) )
# }
# complete -F _django_completion -o default django-admin.py manage.py django-admin

# _python_django_completion()
# {
#     if [[ ${COMP_CWORD} -ge 2 ]]; then
#         PYTHON_EXE=${COMP_WORDS[0]##*/}
#         echo $PYTHON_EXE | egrep "python([2-9]\.[0-9])?" >/dev/null 2>&1
#         if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
#             PYTHON_SCRIPT=${COMP_WORDS[1]##*/}
#             echo $PYTHON_SCRIPT | egrep "manage\.py|django-admin(\.py)?" >/dev/null 2>&1
#             if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
#                 COMPREPLY=( $( COMP_WORDS="${COMP_WORDS[*]:1}" \
#                                COMP_CWORD=$(( COMP_CWORD-1 )) \
#                                DJANGO_AUTO_COMPLETE=1 ${COMP_WORDS[*]} ) )
#             fi
#         fi
#     fi
# }

# # Support for multiple interpreters.
# unset pythons
# if command -v whereis &>/dev/null; then
#     python_interpreters=$(whereis python | cut -d " " -f 2-)
#     for python in $python_interpreters; do
#         pythons="${pythons} ${python##*/}"
#     done
#     pythons=$(echo $pythons | tr " " "\n" | sort -u | tr "\n" " ")
# else
#     pythons=python
# fi

# complete -F _python_django_completion -o default $pythons
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Homebrew, OpenCV
export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/lib/python2.7:$PATH"
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: Did you upgrade the OS or just restore from a backup?  If upgrade, from what to what? Thanks.

Comment: @rholmes, I did not upgrade the OS. I erased the disk and restored from backup (Time Machine).

Comment: You're probably back up and running by now - forgot about this one for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit late for an actual answer but I hope it helps someone with the same problem in the future.

What actually happened:

- I did a fresh install of the OS.
- I used Migration Assistant to migrate my data from Time Machine.  I believe this step corrupted my environment and paths.

The solution was to use [macOS Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) and choose "Restore from Time Machine".

Answer (score 1):

When things like this have happened to me, I usually reinstall Homebrew.  See this link on SO: [Safest way to reinstall Homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038028/what-is-the-best-safest-way-to-reinstall-homebrew)

Afterwards, you may have to recreate your Python Virtualenv (to pick up the right Python binaries and libraries).