# brew error for can't load such file

Tags: homebrew

today i get install new service with brew but get error below

```
Error: cannot load such file -- language/node
Please report this bug:
    https://git.io/brew-troubleshooting
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/kibana.rb:1:in `load_formula'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:21:in `module_eval'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:21:in `load_formula'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:34:in `load_formula_from_path'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:83:in `load_file'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:74:in `klass'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:70:in `get_formula'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:207:in `factory'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/search.rb:164:in `block in search_formulae'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/search.rb:162:in `map'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/search.rb:162:in `search_formulae'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/search.rb:56:in `search'
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb:97:in `<main>'
```

how to fix this, any suggestion? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What solved it for me was to reinstall brew by doing the following:

1. List all installed `Formulae` and `Casks` with: `brew list` (save that list somewhere)
2. Remove Brew and *everything* installed through it with: `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"`  [as found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038028/what-is-the-best-safest-way-to-reinstall-homebrew)
3. Reinstall brew with: `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`
4. Reinstall all `Formulae` and `Casks` with: `brew install <app>`