# FFmpeg macos install Reason: image not found

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, terminal, homebrew

I'm trying to install FFmpeg on my mac.
When I do

```
brew install ffmpeg --with-chromaprint --with-fdk-aac
--with-fontconfig --with-freetype --with-frei0r --with-game-music-emu --with-libass --with-libbluray --with-libbs2b --with-libcaca --with-libgsm --with-libmodplug --with-librsvg --with-libsoxr --with-libssh --with-libvidstab --with-libvorbis --with-libvpx --with-opencore-amr --with-openh264 --with-openjpeg --with-openssl --with-opus --with-rtmpdump --with-rubberband --with-sdl2 --with-snappy --with-speex --with-tesseract --with-theora --with-tools --with-two-lame --with-wavpack --with-webp --with-x265 --with-xz --with-zeromq --with-zimg
```

This happens when I try to use FFmpeg

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/rubberband/lib/librubberband.2.dylib  
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg  
Reason: image not found  
Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This should fix the problem:

```
$ brew reinstall ffmpeg
```

Comment: I confirm this solved my issue when I had following error also: 
 `dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/libffi.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/p11-kit/lib/libp11-kit.0.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6`

Comment: It solved my issue after a macOS upgrading

Answer (score 2):

There is a common issue with brew when upgrading Mac Os as laid out on [brew.sh](https://docs.brew.sh/Common-Issues#upgrading-macos):

> Upgrading macOS Upgrading macOS can cause errors like the following:
>
> dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.54.dylib
> configure: error: Cannot find libz Following a macOS upgrade it may be
> necessary to >reinstall the Xcode Command Line Tools and brew upgrade
>
> > all installed formula:
>
> ```
> xcode-select --install
> brew upgrade
> ```

**1. Step: uninstall command-line-tools**

```
rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

(You probably have to sudo that command, but since you only should use sudo when you know, what you do, I didnt put it in the command). Source: [Aaron Brager on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29859370/5015397).

**2. step: backup installed brew packages**

Then you should back up your installed brew packages by

```
brew bundle
```

this command creates a brews.txt at your current location. check the content by

```
nano brews.txt
```

and leave it by pressing ctrl+x. remember the folder you saved that file in!

source: [Tom Lankhorst](https://tomlankhorst.nl/brew-bundle-restore-backup/).

**3 step: uninstall homebrew**

next step is to uninstall homebrew and all packages by

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
```

source: [Ming C on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36660313/5015397).

**4. step: reinstall everything**

after that you install the command line-tools again by

```
xcode-select --install
```

and install homebrew again by

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

and last but not least you go into the folder you saved the bundle in (if it is in your users home folder, you type "cd ~") and restore all installed packages by

```
brew bundle
```

**Common Issues**

In my case where two packages that could not be installed. One was r, and the error read:

> Could not symlink bin/R
>
> Target /usr/local/bin/R

solution:

```
brew link --overwrite r
```

The other was Chromium:

> Error: It seems there is already an App at '/Applications/Chromium.app'.

solution:

```
rm -r /Applications/Chromium.app/
brew cask install chromium
```

Comment: I didn't need to uninstall xcode, i just uninstall and reinstalled homebrew. I had to use sudo for the uninstall

Comment: "$ brew reinstall ffmpeg" was necessary for me, following macOS upgrade from 10.13 to 10.15