# Homebrew cannot install gcc

Tags: gcc, homebrew

I try to get gcc via homebrew. There are certain weird problems so I delete the homebrew and reinstall it. Re-installation was successful and I follow this: [What is the best/safest way to reinstall Homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038028/what-is-the-best-safest-way-to-reinstall-homebrew)

Now, I simply type `brew install gcc` as usual then I got:

```
brew install gcc
Warning: You are using macOS 10.10.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Discourse, Twitter or IRC. You are responsible for resolving any issues you
experience, as you are running this old version.

Warning: Your Xcode (7.2) is outdated.
Please update to Xcode 7.2.1 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.

==> Installing dependencies for git: pcre2
==> Installing git dependency: pcre2
Warning: Your Xcode (7.2) is outdated.
Please update to Xcode 7.2.1 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.

Updating Homebrew...
Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  RuntimeError: The requested Homebrew GCC was not installed. You must:
  brew install gcc@6

Warning: You are using macOS 10.10.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Discourse, Twitter or IRC. You are responsible for resolving any issues you
experience, as you are running this old version.

Warning: Your Xcode (7.2) is outdated.
Please update to Xcode 7.2.1 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.

==> Installing dependencies for gcc: gmp, isl, mpfr and libmpc
==> Installing gcc dependency: gmp
Warning: Your Xcode (7.2) is outdated.
Please update to Xcode 7.2.1 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.

Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  RuntimeError: The requested Homebrew GCC was not installed. You must:
  brew install gcc@6
```

So, I also follow what error message suggests `brew install gcc@6` then I got

```
brew install gcc@6
Warning: You are using macOS 10.10.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Discourse, Twitter or IRC. You are responsible for resolving any issues you
experience, as you are running this old version.

Warning: Your Xcode (7.2) is outdated.
Please update to Xcode 7.2.1 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.

==> Installing dependencies for git: pcre2
==> Installing git dependency: pcre2
Warning: Your Xcode (7.2) is outdated.
Please update to Xcode 7.2.1 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.

Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  RuntimeError: The requested Homebrew GCC was not installed. You must:
  brew install gcc@6

Updating Homebrew...
Warning: You are using macOS 10.10.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Discourse, Twitter or IRC. You are responsible for resolving any issues you
experience, as you are running this old version.

Warning: Your Xcode (7.2) is outdated.
Please update to Xcode 7.2.1 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.

==> Installing dependencies for gcc@6: gmp, isl, mpfr and libmpc
==> Installing gcc@6 dependency: gmp
Warning: Your Xcode (7.2) is outdated.
Please update to Xcode 7.2.1 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.

Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  RuntimeError: The requested Homebrew GCC was not installed. You must:
  brew install gcc@6
```

which is recursive. My guess about this problem is maybe I am using too old version of OSX? (10.10 Yosemite).

Should I get latest version of OSX to get correct brew functionalities? If you have any thoughts, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the message says, your macOS version is not supported by Homebrew, and you have an outdated Xcode.

Having a non-supported macOS is ok if everything’s work fine for you. However, the outdated Xcode blocks everything.

If you can, update your Xcode and try again. If it stills doesn’t work, you’ll have to update your macOS.