# Broken Homebrew - getting traceback error when typing "brew" + anything

Tags: bash, terminal, homebrew, zsh, macos-catalina

How do I fix this?

I open terminal on my Mac, and in either ZSH or bash, type: "brew", or even "brew doctor", and I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
13: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:23:in `<main>'
12: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:23:in `require_relative'
11: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
10: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 9: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 8: from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/config.rb:56:in `<top (required)>'
 7: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/pathname.rb:578:in `mkpath'
 6: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:200:in `mkdir_p'
 5: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:200:in `each'
 4: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:215:in `block in mkdir_p'
 3: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:215:in `reverse_each'
 2: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
 1: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:239:in `fu_mkdir'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:239:in `mkdir': File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /private/tmp (Errno::EEXIST)
```

I tried:

- Brew doctor: gave the same error
- Uninstalling homebrew and reinstalling it: ends with the same error and "Failed during: /usr/local/bin/brew update --force"
- sudo-ing brew doctor: gave me an error about granting admin privileges and refused to continue.
- tried upgrading ruby:

  - installed RVM,
  - called "rvm install ruby-2.7.0"
  - got the same error about 5 times in a row, after which it gave me:

    Updating system..........
    Installing required packages: autoconf, automake, libtool, pkg-config, coreutils, libyaml, libksba, readline, zlib, openssl@1.1..There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.
    |
    .Try `brew tap --repair` and make sure `brew doctor` looks reasonable.

  Check Homebrew requirements https://docs.brew.sh/Installation
  .
  Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install autoconf automake libtool pkg-config coreutils libyaml libksba readline zlib openssl@1.1',
  please read /Users/myName/.rvm/log/1577488510_ruby-2.7.0/package_install_autoconf_automake_libtool_pkg-config_coreutils_libyaml_libksba_readline_zlib_openssl@1.1.log
  Requirements installation failed with status: 1.

  - tried "brew tap --repair": got the same error.

Running MacOS Catalina 10.15.2

Update 1: 
Managed to install ruby 2.7.0 using rbenv, tried reinstalling homebrew. Same issue.

Update 2:
This mac was built from a Time machine backup, which I'm guessing caused all the trouble. Gonna save the women and children, wipe the drive and clean install.

Comment: This might be of some help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038028/what-is-the-best-safest-way-to-reinstall-homebrew

Comment: I can uninstall it, but the reinstallation doesn't work properly and I end up with the same error. I think it has something to do with ruby, but I need ruby to install homebrew and homebrew to install ruby or RVM. Even macports installations fail.

Comment: Some wild suggestions: Did you give Terminal full disk access? Did you do a gem system update?

Comment: yes and yes. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A clean install of MacOS, without migrating from Time Machine fixed it. yay?

Comment: You could have done `which ruby` to see if it has an executable removed? As you see, every warning has to do with a .rb script

Comment: I did, it was saying version 2.7.0, which is what I had installed using rbenv.

Answer (score 1):

I just got this issue, and looking around the code I found that the issue come from the `HOMEBREW_TEMP` env var.

I've just created a `tmp` local folder in my home and ran the command like that:

```
HOMEBREW_TEMP=~/.tmp brew install gpg
```

Which workaround the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling and reinstalling worked for me.

From [OSXDaily](https://osxdaily.com/2018/08/12/how-uninstall-homebrew-mac/):

> For uninstalling Homebrew in MacOS Catalina, macOS Big Sur, and MacOS
> Mojave:

`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"`

> For uninstalling Homebrew from MacOS High Sierra, Sierra, El Capitan,
> and earlier:

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"`